# Directx9 Direct3DCreate9 crashing program

Tags: c++, dll, directx, direct3d, directx-9

I am writing a simple dll hook to draw on a program, to do this I inject the dll into the process, which than creates a thread where it retrieved the endScene location. In order to retrieve the end scene location, I found the address of "Direct3DCreate9", which I than used to find the vtable. My problem is, Calling the Direct3DCreate9 seems to be crashing the program instantly.

My code is the following, is there something wrong with how I get the Direct3DCreate9 location or something else about it?

```
DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param) {
    // Information
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandleA("d3d9");

    //d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);    // create the Direct3D interface

    // Find adress of create
    LPDIRECT3D9(__stdcall*pDirect3DCreate9)(UINT) = (LPDIRECT3D9(__stdcall*)(UINT))GetProcAddress( module, "Direct3DCreate9");

    // Create the direct3d
    LPDIRECT3D9 pD3D = pDirect3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    // Create IDirect3DDevice9 and destroy
    D3DDISPLAYMODE d3ddm;
    HRESULT hRes = pD3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &d3ddm);
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = true;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = d3ddm.Format;

    IDirect3DDevice9 * ppReturnedDeviceInterface;   // interface IDirect3DDevice9 (pointer to array of pointers)

    // Set the window to program window
    HWND window = FindWindowA(NULL, "test");

    // Create it
    hRes = pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
    D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
    window,
    D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
    &d3dpp,
    &ppReturnedDeviceInterface);

    pD3D->Release();
    DestroyWindow(window);

    unsigned long* pInterface = (unsigned long*)*((unsigned long*)ppReturnedDeviceInterface);

    DWORD endScene = (DWORD)pInterface[42];
    // Output information to log file

    std::fstream test;
    test.open("log.txt", std::ios::out);
    test << endScene;
    test.close();

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)param, 0);

    return (0);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    {
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, MainThread, hModule, 0, NULL);
        break;
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Surely, there's a stack trace together with the faulting instruction. Since you aren't checking for errors, and blindly use the return value of `GetProcAddress`, chances are, that you simply dereference a `nullptr`. You aren't passing the decorated symbol to `GetProcAddress` so that could well be the reason.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried logging the `GetProcAddress(module, "Direct3DCreate9");` and it appears to give a valid pointer to the correct address. Following the process in a debugger, it appears to be causing an access violation, although I am unsure why.

Comment: You need to set up your debugger to break when a Win32 exception is **thrown**. That'll give you the entire callstack with the faulting operation at the top.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for your responses, when checking for the exceptions in debugger and checking through I was able to come across two problems that were causing the errors. For some reason it wasn't getting the correct PID causing directx to fail, also too many threads were being created freezing the program. I'll make sure to do more error checking in the future, didn't think I would need to bother for something so small, but blindly going through it seemed to cause quite a few problems.